sstableloader taking a long time to complete
We are looking to restore Cassandra data from snapshots and incremental backups.
This is a setup with 15 nodes in a single DC.
Snapshots and incremental backups are copied to local disk on each node and sstableloader is being used to stream the data.
The data size is around 170GB on each node with some 2.5 billion rows in total.
The keyspace is setup with a replication factor of 3.
Running sstableloader to stream this data on all the nodes and the tool has been running for 36+ hours.
The cpu and disk resource usage seem to be optimal without any particular spike in disk or network latency.
Is this slowness expected?
Looking for suggestions around what could be the cause for this slowness and how can we reduce the sstableloader streaming time.
Also, is there any benchmarking numbers, particularly around sstableloader, available anywhere which could be referred to.
Thanks!

What is expected for one cluster is not applicable to another because there are a lot of factors that determine the bulk-load throughput.
These factors include (but not limited to):

use case
access patterns
hardware configuration (CPU, network, disks, etc)
data model
cluster load
Cassandra configuration

Only you can determine what is expected for your specific cluster based on your own load tests that you perform using production-like datasets and production-like workloads. Cheers!
